# PHP openssl_pkcs7_verify Not Working

Tags: php, pkcs#7, php-openssl

I`m using pkcs7 to sign a document and everything works fine, the problem is that the command to verify the sign is not working, always return false. I try to use the terminal command into the file and works fine.

**Sign command:**

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign(
    $tempdoc,
    $tempsign,
    $this->signature_data['signcert'],
    array($this->signature_data['privkey'],
    $this->signature_data['password']),
    array(),
    PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED);
```

**Verify command:**

```
openssl_pkcs7_verify($tempsign, PKCS7_NOVERIFY)
```

**Terminal command:**

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in signature.pkcs7 -print_certs -text
```

**EDIT 1**

I make tests in my code and discover if i create my sign with only PKCS7_DETACHED or PKCS7_BINARY works fine the **verify**, but both together i receive the error. Why this is happening?

Comment: Did you forget the dollar in front of `tempsign`?

Comment: Does `openssl_pkcs7_sign` actually succeed? Also see [`PKCS7_sign`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/PKCS7_sign.html) man page. If it fails then you should call `ERR_get_error` immediately to retrieve the error. Also see [`ERR_get_error`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/ERR_get_error.html) man page.

Comment: They don`t fail because the PDF reader successful read the assignature. And a just forget to PUT in the Question the $, but in my code is right.

Comment: After you get the error, what does `echo openssl_error_string();` show?

Comment: error:21071065:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_signatureVerify:digest failure

Comment: @PedroSoares your terminal command only prints out the certificates found in the signature, it does not read data (i.e. `$tempdoc`), correct?

Comment: @PedroSoares do you still need a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here with PHP 7 i can reproduce your problem. With both flags the verify fails.

Maybe [THIS URL](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/smime-tool-binary-and-verify-td44099.html) can help you., this part talks about it.

> SMIME -sign "detached" "attaches" content similarly as-is  with
>   -binary and text-canonicalized without, and signs that.  SMIME -verify recognizes "detached", but (in multi_split)  always canonicalizes both
>   parts before using them. For content  that was sent noncanonical (with
>   -sign -binary or equivalent)  this changes the signed content, and verify fails.  Content that was canonical as sent (originally
>   canonical  or canonicalized by sender) does verify and similarly  is
>   output without determining if sender changed it.

In the [docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/smime.html) you can read that the parser isn't that smart:

> **BUGS**
>
> The MIME parser isn't very clever: it seems to handle most messages
>   that I've thrown at it but it may choke on others.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The link is broken now, is there a solution on how to verify when signed with DETACHED and BINARY?